# How to Run VBA Script in MS-Word From Where the Cursor Is?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following

```
Sub FormatOMaths()

    Dim formula As OMath

    For Each formula In ActiveDocument.OMaths
        formula.Range.Font.TextColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Next

End Sub
```

This always executes starting from the beginning of the document. How can I modify the script to run from where my cursor is all the way down to the end of the document? Thanks,

Comment: you have to compare range at cursor to range at OMath object

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call my variable `Formula` because that is a word Excel uses itself. You might explore whether Excel will know what you mean and use your meaning instead of its own. As for myself, I don't argue with Excel :-)

```
Dim Frm As OMath

For Each Frm In ActiveDocument.OMaths
    With Frm.Range
        If .Start >= Selection.OMaths(1).Range.Start Then
            .Font.TextColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    End With
Next
```

In case you do wish to argue: Select any variable's name in your code and press F1. You will be informed what Excel needs the same word for, if it uses the same word.